# How does a generic Python library manage settings?

Tags: python, django, settings

I have an existing Django app. Part of it is specific to a Django web app of ours, but another part does a lot of complicated computation, and it may be useful to more of our products. I am busy splitting off this more generic part into a library that *does not depend on Django*.

The Django app has a few settings -- for instance, it needs to know the location of certain data files. In Django I find that location as the `MYAPP_DATA_DIR` setting in `settings.py`, and I use `django-appconf` to set defaults for such settings.

What's the most common way to handle settings for generic Python libraries? Should I have a configure() function that can be called to set up the library, look in environment variables, something else?

Comment: Non-authoritative answer: I would encapsulate library entry point(s) in some class(es) and have those settings as constructor parameters for the class. Much like "Facade" pattern.